# How do I insert a string at more than one position in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I have this two strings in Javascript `20130927` this represent a date and `192600` which is a hour. I want to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to parse them as a valid Date/Time element but before I need to convert to valid date javascript object so I need to transform the string in something like `2013-09-27` or `2013/09/27` (I though both are valid) and `19:26:00`. I read about `slice()` and `substr()` methods but don't get how to use them to achieve the expected result. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` like this:

```
str = "20130927"
year = str.substring(0,4)
month = str.substring(4,6)
day = str.substring(6,8)
```

And then create a new Date object with that like this:

```
new Date(year, month, day)
```

For the time you would do something similar and pass the results as additional parameters to the `Date` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use moment's built in parser.

Something along these lines works for me:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var date = "20130927";
var hour = "192600";
var newDateTime = moment(date+hour, "YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
console.log(newDateTime)
```

outputs:

```
{ _i: '20130927192600',
  _f: 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss',
  _l: undefined,
  _isUTC: false,
  _a: [ 2013, 8, 27, 19, 26, 0, 0 ],
  _d: Fri Sep 27 2013 19:26:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) }
```

See [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for additional info.